# Added an extra variable to a VBA function - now has compile error stating Expected:=

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function that worked fine, until I tried to pass an extra variable to it.  Now the code won't run, and I get an error stating Expected:=, I've tried renaming the function, but no help.

Was - Function GetData(site_add)
Changed to Function GetData(site_add, temporary) and failed - despite changing the call to the function accordingly...!?!

Is it possible that the compiler is glitching and I should focus on that? I have other functions in the code that use 5 call 5 variables and don't even call/use them all...!?  Help...

Answer (score 1):

By adding the second parameter, you are effectively telling the compiler that every call to this method now requires two parameters instead of one. So you have to find everywhere you call the GetData() function and make sure it now passes two parameters instead of one, even if the second parameter is Nothing. Now, if you want it to default to nothing so you don't need to pass it you can rewrite it as

```
GetData(site_add, Optional temporary)
```

*my vb is rusty, so take my example with a grain of salt please.